# loop devices don't go away properly

Tags: linux, loop-device

I have a script that I use to mount diskimages that are LVM images.  it does:

```
x=`losetup -f`       #create a loop device
echo $x > loopdev    #echo that device to a file for later use
losetup $x disk.img  #mount the disk.img to the loop device
kpartx -av $x        #use kpartx to add the partition mappings
vgscan && vgchange -ay   #vgscan the new mappings and make active
mount /dev/VolGroupRoot/LogVolRoot /mnt   #mount the volgroup to /mnt
mount -o loop,offset=$((2048 * 512)) disk.img /mnt/boot    #mount the boot partition in the image to /mnt/boot
```

This works a charm when there are available loop devices.

Alternatively, to then umount the img I run:

```
umount /mnt/boot        #umount boot
umount /mnt             #umount volgroup
vgchange -an VolGroupRoot   #make volgroup inactive
x=`cat loopdev`             #get my used loopdevice
kpartx -d $x                #delete the partition mappings
losetup -d $x               #detach the loop device
/bin/rm loopdev             #remove the loopdev file in prep for the next time I mount something using the script.
```

This runs without errors however,  I find that it doesn't always remove the loop device for later use.  losetup -a often shows those previously used loop devices still in it's table.  dmsetup info doesn't show the loop devices but I do see them with lsof being held by kthreadd.  As a result it appears there's no way to remove the /dev/loop devices without a reboot which seems like taking a sledge hammer to the problem.  I can (and often do) end up building new loop devices to get around this but that's unsustainable and doesn't address the real issue.  has anybody seen this and/or have any other things I can try (fwiw, this is happening on 3.18 and 4.1 kernel systems).

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1224543/losetup-refuses-to-detach